# Number of years passed - Consider leap year

Tags: php, timestamp

In our HR system, we want to calculate the number of years the employee has served the company.

What we have is the joining date in `TIMESTAMP` column.

What I am doing is:

```
$timeNow = time(); // current time
$joinDate = strtotime($users->fields['date_of_joining']); // from database
$servicePeriod = $timeNow - $joinDate; // in seconds
$servicePeriod = $servicePeriod / 31570560; // in years
```

But will this take the leap years into consideration? If an employee joined in `Feb 27` of a leap year and if we check the status next year by `March 1`, he should still be reported as served for `1 year` and not `1 year and 1 day`.

Any ideas on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method seems like an unnecessarily roundabout way to calculate this. How about this (pseudocode):

```
years = current_date.year - start_date.year
if current_date.mmdd < start_date.mmdd:
    years = years - 1
```

Comment: That's how I calculate age too.

Answer (score 0):

You have counted with 365.4 days in a year which is obviously wrong. If you change that to 365.26 (31558464), leap years will be automatically included in the long run, but not if the period is shorter than 4 years. This is in your own advantage, but not in your employees'.

Also, add a last line to round the number down to completed days:

```
$servicePeriod = floor($servicePeriod);
```

Comment: I particularly like the way you chastised the OP for choosing the wrong value then went ahead and used your *own* wrong value :-) It's 365.2425 which takes care of the 4/100/400 rules.

Comment: paxdiablo, the best value to use nowadays is probably 365.25 anyway :-)